# geckodriver not working without selenium with nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

Here's what my nightwatch.json looks like

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "./globals.js",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : false
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 9515,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": false,
      "default_path_prefix": "",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
        "marionette": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here's what my globals.js looks like:

```
var geckodriver = require('geckodriver');
module.exports = {
  before : function(done) {
    geckodriver.start();
    done();
  },

  after : function(done) {
    geckodriver.stop();
    done();
  }
};
```

When I run nightwatch here's what happens:

```
▶ nightwatch

[New] Test Suite
========================

Running:  login
INFO Request: POST /session
 - data:  {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"firefox","javascriptEnabled":true,"acceptSslCerts":true,"platform":"ANY","marionette":true,"name":"New"}}
 - headers:  {"Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Content-Length":148}

Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server

Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9515
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 9515 }
```

I tried to emulate what things looked like for the standalone chrome setup, but I guess I'm missing something or there's a bug that's preventing things from proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the correct port set, woops! I needed to change `selenium_port` to 4444